# How to stop combobox from adding a selectedItem to itemSource list when selecting an item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

In short, I bind the ItemSource of my combobox to a list of objects. I bind the SelectedItem to a property. The problem is: whenever I select an item in the combobox and press a button, the SelectedItem duplicates itself (it even is added in the database). This is not what I want.

I have tried to change the binding Mode and updateSourceTrigger, but this hasn't worked out for me so far. I also have tried to bind my itemssource  to another list (a copy from the database repository), but the problem persists.

XAML (View):

```
 <ComboBox Margin="0,15,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Top" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Table" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedItem="{Binding Reservation.Table}" ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" ></ComboBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Data.Table> Tables
{
    get { return _tables; }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ref _tables, value);
     }
}
```

```
Tables = _tableRepo.GetTables();
```

Button logic:

```
private void Save()
{
    if (IsNewReservation)
    {

        _reservationRepo.AddReservation(Reservation);
    }
    else
    {
        _reservationRepo.UpdateReservation(Reservation);
    }
}
```

Button XAML:

```
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="20" Height="45" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Content="Save">
            <Button.IsEnabled>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HasAllTextConverter}">
                    <!--https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1101746/Need-to-enable-the-button-when-all-textbox-has-val-->
                    <Binding ElementName="LastName" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="AmountPeople" Path="Text"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="Phone" Path="Text"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.IsEnabled>
        </Button>
```

I excpect the SelectedItem to update my property, without having an impact on the source.

Comment: What is the logic of the "button click" you mentioned. Does the item duplicate itself only after you click the button? If so you should post that code as well.

Comment: I just checked and it does indeed only duplicates when the button is pressed. I have added the button logic in the original post.

Comment: Looks like isnewreservation is true when you're expecting it to be false. Which should be easy to confirm if you put a breakpoint in that handler. And the problem is in some code you haven't posted.

Comment: If that were to be true, a new reservation would be created. In this case, a new table is created.

Comment: The problem seems to be inside the _reservationRepo.AddReservation(Reservation); it seems that something is adding the item again to the list, since it is an observable collection it everychange will trigger a notification to update the UI.

Comment: Turns out it had nothing to do with the binding itself, but something was wrong with the databasecontext. No idea how it could trigger this mistake, but it is fixed now. Thank you all for your response.